# Site columns not showing in managed properties, although they are searchable

Tags: site-column, managed-property, refiner

In SharePoint Online, I have created a site column, added data to that column, and reindexed.

It is a text column named **EfipsWhatever**, so it should generate a managed property named **EfipsWhateverOWSTEXT**. And I can indeed find the list item if I issue a search for EfipsWhateverOWSTEXT and even add EfipsWhateverOWSTEXT to the selected properties (see FIGURE A below).

The problem is, however, that *I can't find the property EfipsWhateverOWSTEXT in the Managed Properties of the schema* for the site or the site collection. And if I try mapping a RefinableString*, I can't find the property, either.

This ought to be a no-brainer. Am I missing something, or has the implementation of this feature changed?

I should note that I have repeated this exercise on 3 different tenants, and the result is the same in all cases.

**FIGURE A - this search query works:**
https://[SITE_NAME]/_api/search/query?querytext='EfipsWhateverOWSTEXT:Tinge*'&selectproperties='Title,ListItemID,EfipsWhateverOWSTEXT'

**FIGURE B - part of the search result containing EfipsWhateverOWSTEXT**
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>EfipsWhateverOWSTEXT</d:Key>
<d:Value>Tingelingelater</d:Value>
<d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but I don't do much work on SP online. On prem column doesn't become manged property automatically. It becomes crawled property. You need to create new manged property and map it to the crawled property.

Comment: @MarekSarad, the site column can't be found in Crawled properties, either. As for SharePoint Online, "Some managed properties are generated automatically. One example is when you add a site column to a SharePoint library or list. When search crawls that list it automatically generates a crawled and a managed property for the site column, and a mapping between them." [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-schema?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fManage-the-search-schema-in-SharePoint-Online-d4fab46d-ba41-4c03-9d4c-32b5b33198b6)

Comment: Just asking, did you add that "EfipsWhatever" site column to SharePoint library or list and added some values to that column?

Comment: @MarkoTica, yes, and I can find it using the search API, as you can see above. That is the weird thing about it, if you ask me.

Comment: Try in tenant admin (admin-tenantname) search schema or contact MS (maybe some latest kb update problems)

Comment: @MarkoTica, the tenant level search schema is where I first looked - nothing there, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has some issues with the search engine on serveral tenants where crawled properties are not being created. The current respons is that the Sharepoint team is testing a hotfix and plan to roll this out around the 18th

See SP148979 for details